# JavaScript regex for checking number have % sign or not

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a input field, whether i want to input percent value or flat amount for this i have to check it has ends with % sign or not.

sample input may be

```
12%
12.888%
12.00%
12.00001%
12.123344%
```

or for flat amount

```
100
100.55252
100.254575
```

something like this.

N.B: I want to learn javascript regex ...have any suggestions?

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with jQuery. Regex in JavaScript is **just JavaScript.**

Comment: Let's be honest here. Checking whether the last character of a string is a percent sign doesn't necessarily have much to do with regular expressions either.

Comment: but wanna to do with regex :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery uses JavaScript regular expressions. This is a good starting point https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

For your need, `/[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+%/` will be useful.

Comment: Edited: If you want the dot(for decimal point) to be optional, put a `?` after it.

Comment: Why do you use the '*' on the first character-set but an '+' on the second? Wouldn't this match '.99%' ?

Comment: @dheerosaur I was just wondering if this behaviour is what OP was trying to achieve, as it is not in his samples.

Comment: @Pit: True. I shouldn't have assumed. But, I just made a sample solution and pointed him to a guide.

Answer (score 2):

```
/%$/.test( "35%" ); >> true
/%$/.test( "100" ); >> false
/%$/.test( "35.555%" ); >> true
/%$/.test( "35.555" );  >> false
```

Take a look at Mozilla Developer Network for some more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: what will happend for decimal validation?

Comment: Added the tests for decimals. The $ matches to the end of a line, so if you put any values before the $ it will make sure that the line ends with those values. It doesn't care about any of the other values on the line. (Keep in mind that this will work for numbers and letters, so if you wanted to add to it you could have the regex look for numbers & decimals only)

Answer (score 2):

All of the previous suggestions are excellent.  Depending on your needs, you can choose any of them.  I added a bit more to the following to break out the value for you.  Modify to suit your needs.

```
function getValue(num) {
   var matches=num.match(/(^\s*\d+\.?\d*)(%)?\s*$/);
   var m = false, p = false, v = 0;
   if (matches) {
      m = true;
      p = (matches[2]=="%");
      v = matches[1];
   }
   return {isMatch: m, isPercent: p, value: v};
}

var vals = "12%,12.888%,12.00%,12.00001%,12.123344%,100,100.,100.55252,100.254575,notnum".split(',');
for(var i=0;i<vals.length;i++) {
   var gv = getValue(vals[i]);
   console.log("string="+vals[i],"  isMatch="+gv.isMatch,"  isPercent="+gv.isPercent,"  value="+gv.value);
}
```

Output is:

```
string=12% isMatch=true isPercent=true value=12
string=12.888% isMatch=true isPercent=true value=12.888
string=12.00% isMatch=true isPercent=true value=12.00
string=12.00001% isMatch=true isPercent=true value=12.00001
string=12.123344% isMatch=true isPercent=true value=12.123344
string=100 isMatch=true isPercent=false value=100
string=100. isMatch=true isPercent=false value=100.
string=100.55252 isMatch=true isPercent=false value=100.55252
string=100.254575 isMatch=true isPercent=false value=100.254575
string=notnum isMatch=false isPercent=false value=0
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Anon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224346/anon)
has already suggested, you don't really need to use Regular Expressions to solve this problem. What's wrong with:

```
var number = "12.888%";
if(number[number.length - 1] === '%') {
  //processing...
}
```